# C++ Stringstream values aren't correct? The result is 0?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, hex, stringstream

This is the overloading part that I cannot get to work properly.

```
HexColour HexColour::operator+(const HexColour& other) const
{
HexColour temp;
    stringstream r,g,b;
    stringstream ro, go, bo;
    int x, y, z;
    int xo, yo, zo;

    r << hex << colour[2] << colour[3];
    g << hex << colour[4] << colour[5];
    b << hex << colour[6] << colour[7];

    r >> x;
    g >> y;
    b >> z; 

    ro << hex << other.colour[2] << other.colour[3];
    go << hex << other.colour[4] << other.colour[5];
    bo << hex << other.colour[6] << other.colour[7];

    ro >> xo;
    go >> yo;
    bo >> zo;


    if((x + xo) > 255)
        x = 255;
    else
        x = x + xo;

    if((y + yo) > 255)
        y = 255;
    else
        y += yo;    

    if((z + zo) > 255)
        z = 255;
    else
        z += xo;

    cout << x << " anwer" << endl;
    cout << y << " anwer" << endl;
    cout << z << " anwer" << endl;
```

Up until here everything works perfect the x y z answers are correct; this is the problem part:

```
    r << hex << x; // PROBLEM
    g << hex << y; // PROBLEM
    b << hex << z; // PROBLEM
```

The value of r is 0, why?

```
    cout << hex <<r << endl;

    temp.colour = "0x" + r.str() + g.str() + b.str();

    return temp;
    }
```

The part I print out above this is the correct integer value but r is not the new Hex value??

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please publish a self-contained code so that we can compile and analyze? That is, with a main function provided that is using the main functionality.

Comment: To expand upon what @LaszloPapp just said: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: And to put in plain english: 'colours[]' WTF? Also: what _should_ happen?

Comment: btw look up `std::showbase`

Comment: I would say you have a design problem. If you want to do color arithmetics, then you should use a simpler format, e.g. an integer or float triplet. Only for output or conversion routines, strings and stringstreams should come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all the stringstreams using:

```
r.clear();
```

and then repeat the steps->

```
r<<hex<<x;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `std::stringstream::clear()` does not empty the buffer; it merely resets error flags. That may be useful too, but let's be correct about what this function does.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you really have two problems. First I think the data will be a lot easier to manipulate if you convert from hexadecimal strings into some sort of integer type as early as possible, so all the internal code only has to manipulate integers, not hexadecimal strings.

Second, you're doing too many different things in this one function, and then adding insult to injury by repeating each of those things three times. It would be much better to break this up into some functions, each of which carries out some coherent action.

Instead of a `HexColor` class that supports arbitrary operations, I'd create a `color` (or `colour`, if you prefer) class that supports those arbitrary operations, along with conversions to and from `HexColor`, which you'd use only for input and output.

Inside of the `color` class, the operations would be broken up into more manageable pieces instead of each being a giant monolithic chunk of code, with everything repeated three times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

class color;

struct HexColor {
    std::string colour;
    HexColor(std::string const &colour) : colour(colour) {}
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, HexColor const &h) {
        return os << h.colour;
    }
    HexColor(color const &);
};

class color {
    unsigned val;

    unsigned getr(unsigned in) { return (in >> 0) & 0xff; }
    unsigned getg(unsigned in) { return (in >> 8) & 0xff; }
    unsigned getb(unsigned in) { return (in >> 16) & 0xff; }

    unsigned rgb(unsigned r, unsigned g, unsigned b) {
        return r | (g << 8) | (b << 16);
    }

    unsigned min(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
        return b < a ? b : a;
    }

    unsigned saturating_add(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
        return min(a + b, 255);
    }

public:
    friend class HexColor;

    color(unsigned r, unsigned g, unsigned b) : val(rgb(r, g, b)) {}

    color(HexColor const &h) {
        std::stringstream temp(h.colour.substr(2, 6));
        temp >> std::hex >> val;
    }

    color operator+(color const &other) {
        unsigned r = saturating_add(getr(val), getr(other.val));
        unsigned g = saturating_add(getg(val), getg(other.val));
        unsigned b = saturating_add(getb(val), getb(other.val));
        return color(r, g, b);
    }
};

HexColor::HexColor(color const &c) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0') << std::setprecision(6) << std::hex << c.val;
    colour = "0x" + s.str();
}

#ifdef TEST
int main(){
    color a(HexColor("0x010101"));
    color b(HexColor("0x020202"));

    std::cout << HexColor(a + b) << "\n";

    color c(HexColor("0x123456"));
    color d(HexColor("0x789abc"));

    std::cout << HexColor(c+d) << "\n";
}
#endif
```

That leaves one basic question: whether it makes sense to have the `HexColor` class at all, or if it makes more sense to just roll that little bit of functionality into the `color` class itself (or, perhaps, some free functions in the same namespace). For the moment, I'm leaving it as-is, with `color` mostly doing the manipulation, and `HexColor` dealing with I/O, but in real code I'd think long and hard about having only an `operator>>` and `operator<<` that deal with hexadecimal representation, and everything else just manipulate colors.